# my app starts with previous intent if it's launched from recently launched apps

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, task

my app can be launched in two modes: with empty intent or with intent with special data.

```
    confirmIndex = intent.getIntExtra(CONFIRM_INDEX_PARAM, -1);

    if (confirmIndex == -2) {
        intent.putExtra(CONFIRM_INDEX_PARAM, -1);
        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(0);
        String sum = intent.getStringExtra(SUM_PARAM);
        MobileBankingDialog dialogFragment = new MobileBankingDialog();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putString(SUM_PARAM, sum);
        dialogFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "mobileBankingDialog");


    }
```

I can launch the app with data from pending intent when notification was clicked. The app process this data. And after the user closes application, the next launching from the recently launched apps (long pressing of home button) starts the activity with the previous data as it was started from notification. It's not right behaviour. I want the app was started with intent data only from notification.  (When I launch the app  as usial from decktop it behaves ok and launching with empty intent)

How to empty the intent that was launched from recently launched apps?

Comment: If the activity already exists, you will get your new `Intent` via `onNewIntent()`, not `onCreate()`. Beyond that, you might wish to read the docs on notifications and navigation, in case it helps you: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#NotificationResponse

Comment: This code that I lay out is in just from the onNewIntent() and the same is in onCreate. the problem is only in launching from "recents tasks". Android uses for it the same intent as previous but I need the empty. I need launching with data only from notification.

Comment: @Monotype did you find a solution to your issue?